# Understanding the resulting PageRank scores

Tags: graph, pagerank

I ran pagerank on a multi-directed graph. Each node in my graph has an integer value indicating my prior knowledge regarding its importance. I use this value as personalization value and run nx.pagerank_numpy. However, I have problem understanding the resulting scores of nodes and how I should interpret them.

For example, I see the following situation:
'lag' has a higher pagerank score than 'software' while I believe it shouldn't. My reasons are the following:

1)the personalization values for 'lag' and 'software' are 8 and 32 respectively.
2)the number of inlinks and outlinks are higher for  'software' (in=12) than 'lag' (in=8).
3)the pagerank scores of nodes that are linking to 'software' and the weights of the edges are higher than those linking to 'lag'.

You can download the [graph file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgk1o58sm820t6v/mygraph?dl=0) and the [code](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qipe77s2b4dvjq2/myCode.py?dl=0) I am running.
How can I interpret the fact that 'lag' is getting higher PageRank score than 'software'? Is there something that I am missing?

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide us the code that you're using and the input graph so that we can confirm your results? Right now, we can only speculate.

Comment: It is not that easy to do right away. It has a lot of dependencies and might seem complicated. I try to simplify things and might post the code later. For now, I would appreciate any speculation.

Comment: Without the ability to reproduce your error, we have no way of knowing whether this is a simple programming error in your code or a correct but counterintuitive result from PageRank. I doubt your question can be answered in its current form.

Comment: I added the path to the code and graph file. I will appreciate if you can take a look.

Comment: @templatetypedef : I added the code and the graph file. I really appreciate if you can take a look. Thanks a lot